# How to get the values of a foreign key table in laravel

Tags: join, laravel-4, foreign-keys

Hi I'm trying to get the values of a table that references 2 tables. my tables looks like this

```
pages_content table

page_id   |  content_id
------------------------
1     |       4
6     |       10

pages table

id   |   title 
-----------------
1    |   home
6    |   contact


content table


id   |  content
-----------------
4    |  home page
10   |  contact us
```

I need to reference the pages_content table and get the values that are in the other tables.
I tried this

```
$content = DB::select('select * from pages_content pxc, content c where page_id = '.$page_id.' and content_id = c.id');
```

and I got a syntax error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<p>home page</p> and content_id = c.id' at line 1 (SQL: select * from pages_content pxc, content c where page_id = <p>home page</p> and content_id = c.id) (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/app/views/public/content.blade.php)
```

I also tried a couple of things. If you need me to put up the others that I have tried or if you need anymore information, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is self-explanatory, you have a syntax error in the query and that's because the var $page_id equals < p>home page< /p> (for some reason).

```
right syntax to use near '<p>home page</p> and content_id = c.id' at line 1
```

Also, why not use Eloquent instead of a raw query (Assuming this is a many-to-many relationship)?

```
$contents = Page::find($page_id)->content;

foreach($contents as $c){
    $c->pivot->created_at //or whatever you want to access
}
```